# Displaying multiple map markers in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, perl, google-maps-api-3

working on some perl code in a .cgi file that loops through a hash list of IP addresses, then runs each IP address through a web service that returns that latitude and longitude of the IP address, then it needs to display each IP address as a marker on a google map. As of right now I have it running through the hashlist and printing the coordinates of each IP address. What I can't figure out is how to display more than one map marker on the google map. I am currently just testing it by hardcoding values to the $latitude and $longitude variables. I am thinking that there needs to be some sort of loop in the javascript that will run through and assignin each coordinate, but I have no idea on how to approach that.

Update: I have added the code from the first answer and have the list successfully printing outside of the loop. The problem I am having now is that the google map will no longer load. I have narrowed the problem down to the javascript where the latitudes and longitudes variable assigned its value.

```
unless ($result->fault) {

# Print out the results one by one
my $latitude = "LATITUDE = " . $result->valueof('//LATITUDE') . "\n";
my $longitude = "LONGITUDE = " . $result->valueof('//LONGITUDE') . "\n";

#print "MESSAGE = " . $result->valueof('//MESSAGE') . "\n";


$lats .= $latitude . ',';
$lons .= $longitude . ',';


} else {

print "IP2Location Web Service Failed!\n";
print join ', ',
$result->faultcode,
$result->faultstring,
$result->faultdetail;

}
}

chop $lats;
chop $lons;

#printing here to test if the variable is making it out of the loop
print $lats ;
print $lons ;

print <<ENDHTML;
<html>
  <head>
<title>IP Lookup Map</title>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, #map_canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//If I comment out the following variables the map will load, not sure what the problem is
    var latitudes = "$lats".split(",");
    var longitudes = "$lons".split(",");

  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44, -90),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);

    // Creating a marker and positioning it on the map
    for(var i = 0; i < latitudes.length; i++){
        var latitude = latitudes[i];
        var longitude = longitudes[i];
    // Creating a marker and positioning it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
        map: map
    });
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you need to save all the latitudes and longitudes, rather than just print them. I'd use 2 globals, outside your unless($result){

```
my $lats = '';
my $lons = '';
....
$lats .= $latitude . ',';
$lons .= $longitude . ',';
```

(You might need a chop($lats); chop($lons) after the loop to remove the last comma) Then in your javascript section:

```
// create two arrays from that lats and lons string using split()
var latitudes = "$lats".split(',');
var longitudes = "$lons".split(',');
.....
// create map code
....
for(var i = 0; i < latitudes.lenght; i++){
    var latitude = latitudes[i];
    var longitude = longitudes[i];
   // Creating a marker and positioning it on the map
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
       map: map
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it and have everything working now. The problem was that the $latitude and $longitude variables where still being assigned a bunch of extra text that was not needed. Now it is just assigned the value.

```
my $latitude = $result->valueof('//LATITUDE');
my $longitude = $result->valueof('//LONGITUDE');
```